# Why can't I load Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, rvm, nokogiri

I installed Nokogiri without any issues by running:

```
$ sudo gem install nokogiri
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.5.9
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for nokogiri-1.5.9...
Installing RDoc documentation for nokogiri-1.5.9...
```

When I run nokogiri.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

require 'nokogiri'

puts "Current directory is: #{ Dir.pwd }"
Dir.chdir("/home/askar/xml_files1") do |dirname|

  puts "Now in: #{ Dir.pwd }"
  xml_files = Dir.glob("ShipmentRequest*.xml")

  if xml_files.empty?
    puts "#{ dirname } is empty."
  else
    xml_files.each do |file|
      doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(file))
      # ... do something with the doc ...
    end
  end
end
```

I got the error:

```
$ ruby nokogiri.rb 
/home/askar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri (LoadError)
  from /home/askar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3, but for some reason it refers to Ruby 1.9.1. Can this be the cause?

Comment: Never use `sudo` to install gems if you use RVM or rbenv to manage your Rubies, unless you're current set to use the "system" Ruby.

Comment: @the Tin Man. Thanks, I'll keep in mind.

Comment: Why am I down voted? I was following installation instruction at  http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html and they're using "sudo" there.

Comment: I'm not sure why you were downvoted, but I can say you didn't apply a sanity check when you followed directions. The instructions on the Nokogiri site have no relationship to use with RVM or rbenv. You, as the "administrator" of your Ruby environment, have to be aware of your situation, and decide whether you should follow their directions to the letter, or apply some knowledge of your environment and rule out some of their advice. You can't say "I did it because they said!", instead you have to rule out things that don't make sense. It's a learning experience for sure, but you're the boss.

Comment: @the Tin Man I agree with you. But stackoverflow.com is not the university. People came here to solve their problems and mistake I made, I believe is forgivable. I would understood if I was asking non-constructive or very generic question. I'm sure the admin who did down vote, it was his subjective opinion, the other admin wouldn't down vote. :)

Comment: I hope the admin who did downvote will reply to my question or cancel his downvote.

Comment: Don't assume it's an admin. They rarely bother down voting. It's more likely it's someone who just got the ability to vote and thinks it's cool to downvote. Don't worry about them. Instead, ask good questions, make sure the information needed to answer the question is in place, and your rating will climb. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Thanks, @the Tin Man ! I agree with you and I leave alone cool downvoters :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you observe closely, the path starts with `/home/askar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429` so the load path should be correct.

Your problem is that you used `sudo` which will do a gem installation for the system ruby. Try again without `sudo`, just

```
gem install nokogiri
```

to install gems for the current rvm ruby.

Comment: Great to hear! Glad i could help.

Comment: Note, it may also be neccessary to run `gem uninstall nokogiri` and/or `sudo uninstall nokogiri` before installing the gem again. It was for me at any rate.

Comment: I am having a *FilePermissionError* (`You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory`) when I do it without `sudo`. If I do it with `sudo`--however--the error prevails.

Comment: @mauroc8: Give the permission to write on the folder (ex: `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/gems/2.3.0`), it should work without `sudo` then.